# Container for Floating Action Button + Snackbar

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I have this hierarchy:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
  <Framelayout/>
  <NestedScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
      <FrameLayout/>
    </LinearLayout>
  </NestedScrollView>
  <FloatingActionButton>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

I call my snackbar with the root view.
With this layout my snackbar works perfectly as i wanted.

How can i achieve that i can load the `FloatingActionButton` dynamically and wrap it into a container?

I tried to wrap it into another `CoordinatorLayout`. So the layout looked like this:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
  <Framelayout/>
  <NestedScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
      <FrameLayout/>
    </LinearLayout>
  </NestedScrollView>
  <CoordinatorLayout> <!-- This is the added container -->
    <FloatingActionButton> <!-- I would like to load it dynamically from another layout file -->
  <CoordinatorLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

The problem with this is that when i call my snackbar it overlaps the `FloatingActionButton`.

I also tried it with a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout instead but then the `FloatingActionButton` wasn't be placed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case i load a content layout inside a class programmatically and don't know on the root layout (the defined xml layout) whether a `FloatingActionButton` will exist. I added the `FloatingActionButton` inside the content layout but it didn't work correctly when `Snackbar` slide up.
I tried using https://github.com/natario1/NestedScrollCoordinatorLayout but it didn't work for me. Solution for me is to add the `FloatingActionButton` programmatically to the root `CoordinatorLayout`. Then it's a direct child of `CoordinatorLayout` and works correctly. Didn't find a solution where i can have nested `CoordinatorLayout` which work correctly.